# Ryanair tickets not showing on checkmytrip

Tags: ryanair, gds

Does anyone know why Ryainair tickets cannot be imported into CheckMyTrip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only import bookings to CheckMyTrip, which were made through Amadeus GDS (since it's a system provided by them).

They also mention this in their [FAQ](https://www.checkmytrip.com/cmtweb/web-desktop.html#/faq):

> Only bookings done on the Amadeus booking system (for travel providers that are customers of Amadeus solutions) can be imported through the manual import feature. Some of these providers do not wish to display their bookings on CheckMyTrip automatically. You can forward your booking confirmation email to trips@checkmytrip.com from the email address linked to your account and the details of your trip will be automatically added in your trip list.

Ryanair however has ended their partnership with Amadeus end of 2017: https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/ryanair-to-end-gds-partnership-with-amadeus/

When you book with Ryanair directly, they don't use a GDS (using it would cost fees, which Ryanair wants to avoid obviously). If you book a Ryanair ticket through an agent, then it's most likely booked on either Sabre or Travelport.

Comment: An update for those who stumble upon this post: This article describes very well how the travelling agency world are organized when it comes to online travel agencys and distribution channels. It certainly leveled up my understanding of how the world of online searching and buying of tickets works:
https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/travelport-vs-amadeus-vs-sabre-gds/

Answer (score 2):

The [CheckMyTrip webpage FAQ](https://www.checkmytrip.com/cmtweb/web-desktop.html#/faq) under the header "Trip Import" says that only travel booked via the Amadeus system will import. Perhaps Ryanair uses another system, or refuses to allow their data to appear.

Here's a screenshot of the text:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused...do they mean that flights not booked with Amadeus *can* or *cannot* be added to CheckMyTrip by forwarding the email message?

Comment: @KeithBennett As I read the text, it says that if the user forwards their booking confirmation to the email address, the details of the trip will be added. There's no distinction (at the submit-by-email stage) between an Amadeus booking and a non-Amadeus booking.